# Is it possible to add a Cancellation Token to http request into request URL itself? ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, cancellation-token

I've a Blazor client which shows a live stream of images coming from a ASP.NET Core (.NET 6) Web Application Server which in turn requests the stream to a camera (multiple cameras actually), which returns a multipart/x-mixed-replace content.

When the user (client side) leaves the page containing the stream of images, I'd like to server to stop requesting the camera live stream. I know I need to use Cancellation Token, as explained [here](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/), but it seems not to work if client side I make the stream request like this:

```
// CameraLive.razor
<img src="CameraSystem/startStreaming">
```

Server side, request is forwarded to the actual device like this (simplified code)

```
// CameraSystemController.cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CameraSystemController : ControllerBase
{
    private string _contentTypeStreaming = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary";
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    [HttpGet("startStreaming")]
    public async Task<IActionResult>StartCameraStreaming(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Stream stream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync("http://[...]", token);
        FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(stream, _contentTypeStreaming) {
            EnableRangeProcessing = true
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Currently, every time a client open CameraLive.razor page, the server request a stream to the camera and returns it. If on the same client I move to another page of the web application and later I re-enter CameraLive.razor, I see the previous request is not canceled and a new one is made. Actually, if I look at task manager, I can see the bandwidth usage is doubled.
The requests are canceled only if I close the browser tab.

I'd like the request to stop as soon as the client moves to another page, as it happens if the client was to be designed this way:

```
// CameraLive.razor
<img src="@_frame">

// CameraLive.razor.cs
private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
private System.IO.Stream _stream;

private void RetrieveLiveStream() {
    _stream = await Http.GetStreamAsync("CameraSystem/startStreaming", _tokenSource.Token);

    // Every time a new piece of stream comes, 
    // I need to extract the frame from it and update the web page
    _frame = ...
    stateHasChanged();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (_tokenSource != null) {
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
        _tokenSource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If I design the client in this second way the cancellation works: as soon as the user moves to another page, the request is canceled (I can see it clearly from the bandwidth usage data)

However I'd have liked to stick with the first solution because

1. It's simpler, I don't have to handle all the frame-extraction related code, and I suppose the way browser does it is more efficient than the way I would do (I've never done it, I just  tried making the request, doing nothing with the result and then leave the page just to make sure that request is actually canceled).
2. I have the feeling that having the browser auto-update the image is more efficient than having me calling StateHasChanged() continuously.

So, from what I get, in order to have the cancellationToken to work properly, I need to send the token from the client along with the http request. However in the first solution it seems like it is not possible to pass the cancellationToken along with the request URL, so I don't know what I should do.

Any advice?

Comment: The cancellation token is a c# object and cannot be included in URLs. It's not clear to me what's the expected behavior here? What means "complexity is handled by the browser"? The browser cancels the request and you can watch for this with your cancellation token. What additional effect should happen if you pass the token in your URL? S.a. https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/

Comment: There's no first option. To cancel the client-side streaming you *have* to implement `IDisposable`. That's how you know the page/component went out of scope. whether because the user navigated somewhere else or because a component was closed. The server has no idea what the browser did, if there was any kind of navigation or not

Comment: I understand. I've edited the question to make it more clear however your point stands. Since I need to use the second solution, @PanagiotisKanavos do you know if is there a way of having the browser automatically process the System.IO.Stream returned from the http request so I don't need to manually extract the frame and call StateHasChanged() continuously?